# What's wrong with the subclass in the program?

Tags: java, inheritance

I recently created a Deck class (which is the super class) and I am trying to create a tester method to see if my class works. 
Here is my Deck Class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The Deck class represents a shuffled deck of cards.
 * It provides several operations including
 *      initialize, shuffle, deal, and check if empty.
*/
public class Deck 
{
/**
 * cards contains all the cards in the deck.
 */
public static List<Card> cards;

/**
 * size is the number of not-yet-dealt cards.
 * Cards are dealt from the top (highest index) down.
 * The next card to be dealt is at size - 1.
 */
private int size;
public static Card cardOne;

/**
 * Creates a new <code>Deck</code> instance.<BR>
 * It pairs each element of ranks with each element of suits,
 * and produces one of the corresponding card.
 * @param ranks is an array containing all of the card ranks.
 * @param suits is an array containing all of the card suits.
 * @param values is an array containing all of the card point values.
 */
public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<13;i++)
    {
        suits[i] = "Heart";
        ranks[i] = cardOne.rank();
        values[i] = cardOne.pointValue();
        cards.add(cardOne);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<13;i++)
    {
        suits[i] = "Spade";
        ranks[i] = cardOne.rank();
        values[i] = cardOne.pointValue();
        cards.add(cardOne);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<13;i++)
    {
        suits[i] = "Club";
        ranks[i] = cardOne.rank();
        values[i] = cardOne.pointValue();
        cards.add(cardOne);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<13;i++)
    {
        suits[i] = "Diamond";
        ranks[i] = cardOne.rank();
        values[i] = cardOne.pointValue();
        cards.add(cardOne);
    }

}


/**
 * Determines if this deck is empty (no undealt cards).
 * @return true if this deck is empty, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isEmpty() 
{
    if(cards.size()==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Accesses the number of undealt cards in this deck.
 * @return the number of undealt cards in this deck.
 */
public static int size() 
{
    return  cards.size();
}

/**
 * Randomly permute the given collection of cards
 * and reset the size to represent the entire deck.
 */
public static List<Card> Shuffled[];
public void shuffle() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
        cards.get(i);

        int k=(int)(Math.random()*100);
        while(k >52 || k<0)
        {
            k=(int)(Math.random()*100);
        }
        if(Shuffled[k]==null)
            Shuffled[k]=(List<Card>) cards.get(i);
    }

}

/**
 * Deals a card from this deck.
 * @return the card just dealt, or null if all the cards have been
 *         previously dealt.
 */
public Card deal() 
{
    int cardDealed= (int)(Math.random()*100);
    while(cardDealed >52 || cardDealed<0)
    {
        cardDealed=(int)(Math.random()*100);
    }
    Shuffled[cardDealed].remove(cardDealed);

    return (Card) Shuffled[cardDealed];
}

/**
 * Generates and returns a string representation of this deck.
 * @return a string representation of this deck.
 */
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    String rtn = "size = " + size + "\nUndealt cards: \n";

    for (int k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        rtn = rtn + cards.get(k);
        if (k != 0) {
            rtn = rtn + ", ";
        }
        if ((size - k) % 2 == 0) {
            // Insert carriage returns so entire deck is visible on console.
            rtn = rtn + "\n";
        }
    }

    rtn = rtn + "\nDealt cards: \n";
    for (int k = cards.size() - 1; k >= size; k--) {
        rtn = rtn + cards.get(k);
        if (k != size) {
            rtn = rtn + ", ";
        }
        if ((k - cards.size()) % 2 == 0) {
            // Insert carriage returns so entire deck is visible on console.
            rtn = rtn + "\n";
        }
    }

    rtn = rtn + "\n";
    return rtn;
   }
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to put together the DeckTester class (which is the subclass). So far I have the following:

```
import java.util.List;

/**
* This is a class that tests the Deck class.
*/
public class DeckTester extends Deck
{
   public static List<Card> cards;

   public DeckTester(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) 
   {
        super(ranks, suits, values);
   }

  /**
  * The main method in this class checks the Deck operations for    consistency.
  * @param args is not used.
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

  }
}
```

I also have a fully functioning Cards class. I'm just not sure how to check the Deck class.

Answer (score 1):

What I can say right away that `tested` class and `tester` class puts together by [composition](http://www.journaldev.com/1325/what-is-composition-in-java-java-composition-example) not by `inheritance`.

So you have to:

1. import `tested` class to `tester`
2. create instance of `tested` class
3. execute some logic of `tested` object
4. Check if it matches your expectations with e.g [Junit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/) or [TestNG](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/)

Comment: I am aware that I need to do that, the issue is, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Nope, you don't aware. `DeckTester` extends `Deck` - completely wrong approach

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rudziankoŭ, using Test classes using composition would be a lot easier.

I'm not gonna go into details about the various settings you can use but this would be an example (using JUnit here)

```
public class DeckTester {

     /**
         Check if deck size is being instantiated correctly
     */
     @Test
     public void testDeckSize() {

         String[] ranks = new String[1]; // Not sure what this should be
         String[] suits = new String[4];
         int[] vals = new int[12];
         Deck deck = new Deck(ranks, suits, vals);
         assert deck.size() == 52;
     }

}
```